# No funciona mi suscripción a un Observer<string>

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo esta suscripción al observer pero nunca ingresa al subscribe

```
this.auth.refreshToken().
     subscribe(data => { 
     console.log("esto tiene la data" + data);
       this.auth.setToken(data);   
     return next.handle(req);
     }),
     error => { 
     this.auth.logout();
     }
     }
```

En el refreshToken tengo esto:

```
 refreshToken():Observable<string>{
   return this.http
   .get(this.config.getConfig("host")  + "/login/renueva")
   .pipe(
     map(ret => {
       return JSON.stringify(ret);
     })
   );
}
```

qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Sin el pipe funciona?

Comment: no, @JuanAntonio, sigue igual..

Comment: Hola. Posiblemente la api te esta mandon un error . Junto al map pon `cathError(err=> { console.log(err);  return throwError(err)})`. No se si este bien escrito. Todo se importa de las librerias de `rxJS`